# Confirmation msg between Agents

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have a `Sender` that reads from a file and sends each line to a `Receiver` agent.

Typically, I want my `Receiver` agent to send a confirmation for every line received line and the `Sender` Agent is blocked (or waits) until that confirmation is received.

Here is a snap-code of the `Sender` agent

```
private volatile boolean recieved = false;
// Codes and 

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // SENDING LINES ...
                String Agentname="Sender";
                ACLMessage aclMessage= new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CONFIRM);
                aclMessage.addReceiver(new AID(Agentname,AID.ISLOCALNAME));
                aclMessage.setContent(line);
                send(aclMessage);
                if (isRecieved() == false ) { block(); return; }
                System.out.println("Value after "+isRecieved());
            }
```

for recieving the ACLMessages:

```
                    if (msg == null) {
                        block();
                        return;
                    }
                    else {

                        switch (msg.getPerformative()) {
// Other cases
                        case ACLMessage.INFORM:
                            System.out.println("Confirmation");
                            setRecieved(true);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }
```

The Receiver agent when it receives the message it sends a confirmation

```
                case ACLMessage.CONFIRM:

                    // Process the results
                    String result = doNormalize (msg.getContent());
                    if (result!=null) {
                        //send the results to the writer
                        ACLMessage aclMessage= new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CONFIRM);
                        aclMessage.addReceiver(new AID("Writer",AID.ISLOCALNAME));
                        aclMessage.setContent(result);
                        send(aclMessage);

// Sends a confirmation to using the method sendConfirmation
                        sendConfirmation(msg);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                     break;
                    }
    // Code ..
    // ..
   // ..
   // ..

    public void sendConfirmation(ACLMessage aclMessage) {
    ACLMessage message = aclMessage.createReply();
    message.setPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
    send(message);
}
```

So the sender uses a flag value that helps determine whether a confirmation is received or not. For this, it uses the `isRecieved()` method, if it is false, Ideally the agent should be blocked and wait for the confirmation message.

The **problem** is when I run the code it, the `Sender` is blocked when `recieved() == false` is `true`, but it doesn't resume the `while` loop when it receives the confirmation. Am I doing this wrong ?

Comment: Does everything run on one thread ? Can you give the send code ?

Comment: Yes everything on one thread. The send code is the default send method provided by Jade.

Comment: If everything run on one thread, why do you need blocking mechanism as no other thread is going to "wake" them ?

Comment: The block() puts the Behaviour on hold until the next message is received. This is why we use: if (msg == null) { block(); return; } when receiving ACLMessages.

Comment: is sender's behaviour that has loop a OneShotBehaviour or CycleBehaviour?

Comment: The switch-case statement of both the Reciever and Sender agents is inside a CyclicBehaviour. The problem is that when I use the block(); return; statement in the Sender agent, it leaves the while loop and **does** receive the confirmation message, but the agent then stops after that. Normally, it should resume executing the while loop. I hope I was clear.

Comment: I meant the behaviour with "while" statement.Agent should resume execution of the behaviour but not exactly the while loop.

Comment: The Behaviour with the while loop is a OneShotBehaviour. So are you saying that it is not possible? Do you have any other approaches to this?

Comment: added answer with the code.

Comment: I have found the answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block an agents behaviour there various methods :

- `receive()` - nonblocking receive, returns first message in queue or `null` if queue is empty
- `receive(MessageTemplate pattern)` - behaves like the the previous one, but you can also specify pattern for message, like for example specific sender AID, conversation ID, also combinations.
- `blockingReceive()` - blocking receive, blocks agent until message appears in queue
- `blockingReceive(MessageTemplate pattern)` - blocking receive, with pattern

So adding the `blockingReceive()` or `blockingReceive(MessageTemplate pattern)` blocks the agents `Behaviour` until a certain message is received. Which will look something like this:

```
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                // SENDING EVENT LINES ...
                String Agentname="Reciever";
                ACLMessage aclMessage= new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CONFIRM);
                aclMessage.addReceiver(new AID(Agentname,AID.ISLOCALNAME));
                aclMessage.setContent(line);
                send(aclMessage);
                // Block an Agent until a confirmation is received..
                ACLMessage aclMessage2 = blockingReceive(mt);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the behaviour with a switch statement, something like this:

```
public class ReadBehaviour extends Behaviour {
   private boolean isDone = false;
   private int step = 0;
   private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

   @Override
   public void action() {
       switch (step){
           case 0:
               // TODO initialize your bufferedReader
               step++;
               break;
           case 1:
               try {
                   String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                   if(line == null){
                       isDone = true;
                   } else {
                       ACLMessage aclMessage= new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CONFIRM);
                       aclMessage.addReceiver(new AID("Sender", AID.ISLOCALNAME));
                       aclMessage.setContent(line);
                       myAgent.send(aclMessage);
                       step++;
                   }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   isDone = true;
               }
               break;
           case 2:
               if(isRecieved()){
                   step--;
               } else {
                   block();
               }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean done() {
       return isDone;
   }
}
```